# Referencing DLL Class with Strings

Tags: c#

Is this possible?

I have a DLL i have been making, in it is a class called ModbusClient and another named ModbusRTU. In another application i add the following code.

```
ModbusClient Client = new ModbusClient(new ModbusRTU());
```

It works, but now what I'm trying to do is to add the Client dynamically from three strings! Like the following code.

```
string string1 = "Modbus";
string string2 = "Client";
string string3 = "RTU";

string1+string2 Client = new string1+string2(new string1 + string3());
```

I know the code snippet above will never work but, I believe it will best reflect my idea.

Comment: You have a misconception, where did you get this type of syntax:  `string1+string2 Client = new string1+string2(new string1 + string3());`

Comment: @NiksonKantiPaul OP knows this is not possible...It was just illustration to show what OP wants...not to be taken literally

Comment: This appears to be the beginning steps that ultimately end up with [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).  Why are you trying to create these types from string names?

Answer (score 5):

You can use reflection..

```
string string1 = "Modbus";
string string2 = "Client";
string string3 = "RTU";
var modbusClientType = Type.GetType(string1+string2);
var modbusRtuType = Type.GetType(string1+ string3);

var modbusRtuInstance = Ativator.CreateInstance(modbusRtuType);
var modbusClientInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(modbusClientType,modbusRtuInstance);
```

Answer (score 1):

### **-UPDATE-**

I would like to start by thanking everyone that responded to my question. I took Viru's advice and used the "GetType" method. At first it didn't work, but i was able to tweak it a little to get the desired affect. This is how it looks now, and works great for what i needed. By the way DataExchange.Modbus is the DLL's name that i referenced on my original post.

```
string string1 = "Modbus";
string string2 = "Client";
string string3 = "RTU";
var modbusClientType = Type.GetType("DataExchange.Modbus." + string1 + string2 + ",DataExchange.Modbus");
var modbusRtuType = Type.GetType("DataExchange.Modbus." + string1 + string3 + ",DataExchange.Modbus");

var modbusRtuInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(modbusRtuType);
var Client = Activator.CreateInstance(modbusClientType, modbusRtuInstance);
```

After doing this I started scratching my head on how to get and set properties, fields, and run Methods. I looked around for awhile and found out to do it using System.Reflection again like Viru advised.

```
//Type
var t = Client.GetType();

//Properties "Changes the name property of Client"
PropertyInfo Client_Name = t.GetProperty("Name");
Client_Name.SetValue(Client, "NEW NAME");

//Registers "Gets an array from the Client"
FieldInfo Registers = t.GetField("Registers");
Array arr = (Array)Registers.GetValue(Client);
Label_Register1.Text = String.Format("0x{0:x4}", arr.GetValue(246));
Label_Register2.Text = String.Format("0x{0:x4}", arr.GetValue(247));

//Mothods "Executes a method with parameters {_portClient to , 1 }"
MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Execute");
method.Invoke(Client, new object[] { _portClient, Convert.ToByte(1), Convert.ToByte(4), 247, 2, 1 });
```

I hope this helps someone out!! Thank you again for everyone that posted!

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary or some other collection to keep references of dynamically created objects, like below. If what you want is truly dynamic code, you will have to take advantage of Roslyn, or use some scripting sandbox.

```
var dictClients = new Dictionary<string, ModbusClient>();

dictClients.Add("SomeKey", new ModbusClient(new ModbusRTU()));

var someClient = dictClients["SomeKey"];
```